# android return non-null typeface by kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-typeface

I am practicing to convert java code to Kotlin code:

```
class TypefaceProvider {
    companion object {
        private var tmpTypeface = Hashtable<String,Typeface>()
        @JvmStatic
        fun getTypeface(context : Context, dir : String, name : String) : Typeface {
            var createTypeface : Typeface? = tmpTypeface[name]
            if(createTypeface == null){
                createTypeface = try{
                    Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets,"$dir/$name")
                } catch (e : Exception){
                    Log.e(TAG, "fail. msg:${e.message}")
                    Typeface.DEFAULT
                } finally {
                    tmpTypeface[name] = createTypeface 
                }
            }
            return createTypeface <--- wrong, type mismatch
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return an non-null typeface object,

I have already checked `createTypeface` is not `null`.

How to fix the return type mismatch problem?

Should I use `return createTypeface!!` or

`createTypeface?:Typeface.DEFAULT` (but `Typeface.DEFAULT` is duplicate)

or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There short answer is -- If you are making sure `createTypeface` is truly not `null`, returning `createTypeface!!` is safe to do.  You are asserting something you know to be true.  It appears you are doing that, so `!!` should work fine in this case.

In general, if you want Kotlin to infer that something is not `null`, you need to make sure you never have null as possible value for it.  One option for your example is to collapse your null check into a `?:` operator --

```
class TypefaceProvider {
    companion object {
        private var tmpTypeface = Hashtable<String, Typeface>()
        @JvmStatic
        fun getTypeface(context: Context, dir: String, name: String): Typeface {
            val createTypeface = tmpTypeface[name] ?: try {
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "$dir/$name")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "fail. msg:${e.message}")
                Typeface.DEFAULT
            }
            tmpTypeface[name] = createTypeface`
            return createTypeface
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we had to pull the `tmpTypeface[name] = createTypeface` out of the `finally` block. It causes your cache to always save a `null` value (see @Alexy Romanov's comment below). As an aside, I feel it is better to not have it in the finally block anyway, a side-effect inside a variable assignment seems odd.  Also, we don't have to give `createTypeface` and explicit type since it can be inferred.

If you want something more readable, you can break the loading/caching logic into a separate method --

```
class TypefaceProvider {
    companion object {
        private var tmpTypeface = Hashtable<String, Typeface>()

        private fun loadTypeFace(context: Context, dir: String, name: String): Typeface {
            val typeface = try {
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "$dir/$name")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Typeface.DEFAULT
            }
            tmpTypeface[name] = typeface
            return typeface
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun getTypeface(context: Context, dir: String, name: String) = 
            tmpTypeface[name] ?: loadTypeFace(context, dir, name)
    }
}
```

Comment: "(As an aside, I feel it is better to not have it in the finally block anyway, a side-effect inside a variable assignment seems odd)." It's even worse: the finally block will get executed as part of `try` before `createTypeface` gets assigned, so it's always equivalent to `tmpTypeface[name] = null`.